# Phonegap send location without hacking possibilities

Tags: cordova, mobile, location

I'd like to get geoposition of users in my Phonegap app, but in a secure way.

Since Phonegap is web pages based, with Javascript, you can easily hack decompiling app or just sniffing network, so you can see the URL where the app is sending the data (for example; http://api.mycompany.com/sendLocation?lat=50&lng=-65), and therefore you can change this before sending .

Is there any way (in Phonegap, not native) to be sure the user can't hack this and send you other location ?

Comment: First use https, second use POST instead of GET and third use this plugin for encrypt your app: https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Comment: With https and post, we avoid network sniffing.  With that plugin (awesome, I didn't know it!) we avoid source code sniffing.  Seems pretty good ! thank you !

Comment: While https may help prevent an attacker from changing another user's location, but it does nothing to keep a user from changing their own location.

Comment: Joerg, FSQ below says that plugin is useless :P

Comment: @FlamingMoe the plugin is usefull, but you can decompile every app, but it's hard. The fourth point you can do, you can have a kind of authorization on the server and have a session key.

Comment: An authorization/session_key has nothing to do with "changing lat/lng" ... I can't know if the user spoofed lat/lng although I use a key ... how you meant ?

Comment: You can use the hash or a part of the hash for dynamic encryption. If you use this all together you will not have 100% security, but it will be very hard to crack it.

Comment: Please, can I ask you to explain me a little further the stuff of "part of the hash with dynamic encryption" ? Also, if you put this as an answer I will select as winner ;-)  THANK YOU !

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way to do this. You can make it harder, but it is simply impossible to guarantee that the data you receive is from an un-tampered version of your application.

If you do want to make it harder, here are some things you can try:

1. Obfuscate your code: Use a tool like [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to make it harder for attackers to understand your app
2. Retrieve key from server; have your app fetch a key to encrypt its requests from the server when it starts up, and stash that key using the [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) or [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/KeyManagementAPIs/KeyManagementAPIs.html) key storing functions.
3. Use Strict HTTPS: Include your server's public key in your application, and force your application to only use connections to servers with that key.

Comment: FSQ, what about what Joerg said above ?

Comment: I was not clear in my original answer; I edited it to convey the salient point.

Comment: @FlamingMoe; you still have to distribute the key with that plugin. So a user can still get the key, and decrypt your files.

Comment: @FlamingMoe: I've edited my post to add some things you can try